# remote connection from work desktop to home laptop

Tags: display, vnc, windows-subsystem-for-linux

TL;DR : I need the easiest, least bandpass requiring way to control Linux desktop from Windows laptop

I am working from home and trying to find the most convenient way to work on my Linux desktop at work from my windows laptop at home. I have a VPN from the laptop. Some of the work requires a display, since we have a dedicated application that can only run on Linux
The other thing is that I don't have access to the files from my home laptop, because these are the settings of the VPN.

We use MobaXTerm for VNC, which is OK, but I wanted to know whether anyone can recommend other options.

I have tried using ssh from WSL to the desktop and ssh -X back so that I will be able to see any X displays from the Linux that I work n (I have installed an X server in Windows) but I can't connect to my Linux back to my home Windows laptop (even the ping didn't work) when I try to use the IP given me by the VPN. It doesn't work with the host name either. 
I have tried to make the display work from WSL according to this tutorial: https://www.illuminiastudios.com/dev-diaries/ssh-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux/

Does anybody have any advice?

Comment: a while ago I have used xming and putty. You can check here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/190200/how-can-i-remotely-access-my-linux-gui

Comment: Go to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software#Operating_system_support then move right to Linux Client and Linux Server. Sort on each, and you will see what else is out there.